# set ID value for another field

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Can I set the model record ID for another field value? (without `update` it)

In the other way, mix this code to one or two line:

```
$this->Model->create($data);
$this->Model->save();

$this->Model->create($data); // create again
$this->Model->set('link', $this->Model->id); // get record id
$this->Model->save(); // update
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're going to need to clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry, there is not enough code. What do you want? Two times $this->model?

Comment: @Dave: maybe, when we insert data in a table, we have an `id`, i want to set this `id` for another column value, for example (a record): `id` = 10, `title` = 'Post', `text` = 'HelloWorld', 'link' = 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need to make the proper calls to the proper model methods. You will also need to make certain you are storing the information correctly in the array you are passing to save. So let's say you are adding a record to the `places` table. Let's say your schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE 'places' (
`id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
`reference_id` CHAR(36) NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Then you have the following:

```
$data['Place']['name'] = 'New York';

// create the first record to get the PK ID that will 
// be used in the reference_id of the next record

$this->Place->create();
$this->Place->save($data);

// set the reference ID to the ID of the previously saved record
$data['Place']['reference_id'] = $this->Place->id;

// create the next record recording the previous ID as
// the reference_id
$this->Place->create();
$this->Place->save($data);
```

Comment: yes, but the second `save` means `update` the record. doesn't it?

Comment: No for two reasons. 1- you are not passing the `id` which is the primary key for the previous record (meaning there is no $data['Place']['id']` so it doesn't know what to update. 2- `$this->Place->create();` indicates you are creating a new record. If either of these were not true, it would update. But because they are both true, it will save a new record.